# prevent enter submitting form, allow enter in inputs

Tags: jquery

I want enter to be pressed so the focus changes from the current to the next input.  I've done this but i'm having a problem.  The form submits when enter is pressed.

```
$('.length_input input[type=text], .qty').keypress(function(event) {
  if(event.which == 13) {
   //enter pressed
     active($(this));
   }
});
```

How do i allow enter to be pressed on inputs but prevent the form for submitting?  I have a submit button to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) should be used to prevent the default action of enter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action on the form.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
$('.length_input input[type=text], .qty').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        //enter pressed
        active($(this));
    }
});
```